# Problems Add/Update Big Data on PostgresSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to add large amounts of data to the table. 
Before adding, I check whether the data exists in the table or not.

I am dealing with the following:

Example:

Table `users`

`id | name | address`

`.. | .... | .......`

```
select id from users where id = ... and name = ...

if not exist

insert....

if exist

update ....
```

My problem is the time taken too long. 
I wonder if everyone has a solution to solve this problem faster?

Answer (score 3):

You actually do not need to perform this *check* manually. It is rather the job of a constraint, e.g. via a primary key.

Table with a primary key constraint based on `id` and `name`:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
id INT, name TEXT, address TEXT,
PRIMARY KEY (id,name));
```

So, if you try to insert two records with the same `id` and `name` you will get an exception - the error message bellow is in German, but it basically says that the pk constraint was violated:

```
INSERT INTO users VALUES (1,'foo','add 1');
INSERT INTO users VALUES (1,'foo','add 2');

FEHLER:  doppelter Schlüsselwert verletzt Unique-Constraint »users_pkey«
DETAIL:  Schlüssel »(id, name)=(1, foo)« existiert bereits.
```

In case you want to update `address` when `id` and `name` already exist, try using an `UPSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO users VALUES (1,'foo','add x')
ON CONFLICT (id, name) 
DO UPDATE SET address = EXCLUDED.address;
```

If you want to simply ignore the conflicting insert without raising an exception, just do as follows:

```
INSERT INTO users VALUES (1,'foo','add x')
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

See this [`answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51375782/2275388) for more details.

**Regarding speed**: you have to rather check if your table has a proper index or even if an index makes sense at all when performing the insert. Sometimes importing large amount of data into a temporary [`UNLOGGED TABLE`](https://blog.nukomeet.com/faster-inserts-how-to-increase-postgresql-write-performance-24d76bd56f75) table **without index**, and then populating the target table with an SQL removing the duplicates is the best choice.